# Disable minor mode when in another minor mode

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs, hooks, cider

I'm running a distribution of spacemacs and am currently working in clojure's cider debugger, and an issue I've run into is that several of the `cider--debug-mode` keybindings are shadowed by `evil-mode`. I've tried a few things with my configuration so far, including adding a hook on the `cider--debug-mode` which defines a keybinding to allow me to use the keys for their intended purpose again, which didn't work, and I've also simply called `(evil-mode)` in the lambda as well since just calling the function with no args will toggle the mode. However I've continued to experience the shadowed keybinds regardless. When I manually disable `evil-mode` before beginning debugging it works as intended, so it seems to me almost as if the hook isn't running properly.

*Why might that be?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No `(evil-mode)` called non-interactively does not toggle. It unconditionally switches `evil-mode` on. You have to call `(evil-mode -1)` in your program to switch `evil-mode` off.

See the [doc of `define-minor-mode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Minor-Modes.html):

> The toggle command takes one optional (prefix) argument. If called interactively with no argument it toggles the mode on or off. A positive prefix argument enables the mode, any other prefix argument disables it. **From Lisp, an argument of toggle toggles the mode, whereas an omitted or nil argument enables the mode.** This makes it easy to enable the minor mode in a major mode hook, for example. If doc is nil, the macro supplies a default documentation string explaining the above.

Comment: This gave me an almost-correct solution. I used
`(add-hook 'cider--debug-mode-hook '(lambda () (if (bound-and-true-p cider--debug-mode) (evil-mode -1) (evil-mode 1))))`
and it seemed to work.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an actual solution to the problem you've encountered:

```
(defun my-cider-debug-setup ()
  (evil-make-overriding-map cider--debug-mode-map 'normal)
  (evil-normalize-keymaps))

(add-hook 'cider--debug-mode-hook 'my-cider-debug-setup)
```

It will make debug keys work with CIDER while not disabling Evil.

Comment: Could you also elaborate wrt the question ("*Why might that be?*")?

Comment: That has been answered thoroughly in the other solution.

Comment: Unfortunately when I added this to my configuration it seemed to have no effect whatsoever. One odd things I noticed however was that it seemed that I either couldn't evaluate the function, or that M-x was unable to find it. In any case I tried to inline it as a lambda and it still didn't work properly.

Comment: I'm on a stable version of CIDER, so who knows, maybe they changed things meanwhile.